# Firebase console doesn't show crash logs

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, crashlytics

Our app shows 97.43% of users who haven't encountered crashes on the firebase console, but we can't see any crash logs on the firebase console. Has anyone encountered this problem? How to deal with it?

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/Dh9HHygbWTQ, where it might fit better

Comment: Are there missing dSYMs? Check the dSYMs tab in the Crashlytics dashboard.